# How to use ESLint to implement a method

Tags: node.js, eslint

I use `ESLint` to lint my code and I want to implement the `stream.Writable`. I can successfully run my code but ESLint report an error message:

> [eslint] Expected 'this' to be used by class method '_write'. (class-methods-use-this)

I try to find the solution on the ESLint page. It says I can make the `_write` method `static`. But it causes an error when I add the `static` in front of the `_write`.

> Error: _write() is not implemented

Here is my code. Are there have any way to fix it? Or I should make an exception of ESLint?

```
class MyWritable extends stream.Writable {
  _write(chunk, encoding, next) {
    console.log(chunk.toString());
    next();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you transform your method to a static one, you need to call it from the class and not the instance, like this: `MyWritable._write(...)`.

If you are currently developing your method and at term it will use `this` you can disable the rule for the method or the file. You can also completely disable the rule if you feel it's not helping you write better code.